# How to add a context paramter to only a single webapp in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, tomcat6, tomcat8

The doc says this is the way to send a parameter to a webapp from server.xml:

```
<Context>
  ...
  <Parameter name="companyName" value="My Company, Incorporated"
         override="false"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

I think that by default this will send the companyName value to the all the webapps.

How can send this parameter to only a single webapp

Note, I understand you can add entries to the /WEB-INF/web.xml file in the webapp.  However, I want a solution that is setting at the tomcat level.  I don't want to have to edit the war file at all.

Is there another way to send this parameter to only a single webapp?

GC

Comment: Do you mean `conf/server.xml` or `conf/context.xml`? One will work as you describe and the other won't do anything at all like what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't add it to the server.xml file if you don't want it across all webapps.
Instead you would have to add it to the context.xml file in your META-INF folder of your project which would require changing your war.

Comment: I know that solution.  I ma looking for a solution that allows my to set the value once, and not have update it each time the .war is replaced.

Comment: Since its added to your project,every time you deploy the war,it gets bundled within it,so you don't really need to change it unless you want to.
And as I mentioned,you cannot do it exactly in the way you want to as it goes against the server specifications.
In case you do manage to find a different solution then definitely share it with us.

Comment: Also read this for all possible ways of defining context:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Answer (score 0):

`<Context>` with no docbase, path, etc. is not valid in `server.xml`, so you have accomplished nothing with the configuration posted in your question. I would expect Tomcat not to start given that configuration.

If you had a proper configuration, the `<Parameter>` would only affect the context in which it had been defined.

If you put your `<Parameter>` in `conf/context.xml`, then you will in fact define this parameter across every context deployed in your Tomcat instance.

If you want to override the `META-INF/context.xml` that comes bundled in the web application (because you don't want to have to add a `<Parameter>` every time you roll a new release), you should use the well-documented technique of overriding the web application's `META-INF/context.xml` by providing your own in [`conf/[engine]/[host]/[appname].xml`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

Comment: Does conf/[engine]/[host]/[appname].xml override the entire file or just part of the app's web.xml?

Comment: `conf/[engine]/[host]/[appname].xml` overrides no part of `web.xml` at all.

Comment: I think you have the right idea.  I can't test it right now, However, you idea seems right.   I will probably be back on this in a few weeks.